# Make Internet Explorer show the full URL path in the title bar as seen in status bar

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

How do I get Internet Explorer 8 to display every single web page with its own title?

I want the full URL of the web page I am viewing to be displayed in the title bar, and so in the task bar button too.

Windows XP and IE8. Tabbed Browsing is off.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the built-in behaviour of a web browser when it is written to display the text contained in the `<title>` tags of an HTML document.

That said, the following [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) works in Firefox, Opera, Safari and Google Chrome, but unfortunately does not work(*) in any version of Internet Explorer from 6 through 8 that I tested it in:

```
javascript:void(window.document.title=window.location.href);
```

(*) - It actually does seem to set `document.title` to the requested value in Internet Explorer, but does not update the titlebar.

Your options for Internet Explorer at this point are:

1. Have all your web traffic go through a proxy that appends `<script>document.title=window.location.href</script>` immediately before `</body>` for every document.
2. Use some sort of server-side solution to frame every page you want to browse to and control the `<title>` of the top-level frameset document yourself.